# .net - How to change exception message of Exception object?

Tags: .net, exception

How can i change the `Message` of an Exception object in C#?

### Bonus Chatter

The `Message` property of `Exception` is *read-only*:

```
public virtual string Message { get; }
```

### Additional Reading

The same question, in PHP, was answered, *"You can't"*, but gave a workaround:

> You can however determine it's class name and code, and throw a new one, of the same class, with same code, but with different message.

How can i determine an exception's class name, and throw a new one of the same class, but with a different message, in C#?

e.g.:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   Exception e2 = Activator.CreateInstance(e.GetType());
   throw e2;
}
```

doesn't work because the `Message` property of an exception is read-only and .NET. See original question.

---

**Update**

i tried catching each type of exception i expect:

```
try
{
    reader.Read();
}
catch (OleDbException e)
{
   throw new OleDbException(e, sql);
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
   throw new SqlException (e, sql);
}
catch (IBM.DbException e)
{
   throw new IBM.DbException(e, sql);
}
catch (OdbcException e)
{
   throw new OdbcException (e, sql);
}
catch (OracleException e)
{
   throw new OracleException (e, sql);
}
```

Except that now my code forces a dependency on assemblies that won't be present in every solution.

Also, now the exception seems to come from my code, rather than the line that threw it; i lose the exception's location information

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i found the solution in [a blog post](http://tech.blinemedical.com/when-its-good-to-catch-exception-ex/)  linked from [a news site](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/12ecjv/when_its_good_to_catchexception_ex_breaking_the/):

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   Exception e2 = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(e.GetType(), message, e);
   throw e2;
}
```

It's not perfect (you lose your stack trace); but that's the nature of .NET.

Comment: Theoretically that exception type might not have a ctor that takes two arguments.

Comment: You are creating a new Exception and passing a new Exception to it and the original exception as the inner exception. This does not change the Message of the original exception.

Answer (score 40):

You create a new `Exception` (or – better – specific subtype) that has the new message (and pass the original exception as `InnerException`).

Eg.

```
throw new MyExceptionType("Some interesting message", originalException);
```

NB. If you really want to use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) you can use an overload that can be passed parameters, but different Exception derived types cannot be relied on to have an constructor overload for `(message, innerException)`.

Comment: Problem with throwing a new exception is that the new exception is thrown where the new exception is `thrown`. If there was a way to substitute the stack of my new `throw` with that of `InnerException`, or a way to retroactively throw where the current exception came from, it would work. i **have** been throwing my own custom exceptions, but it's a temporary workaround that i need a real solution for [(hence the SO question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334182/net-how-to-change-exception-message-of-exception-object)

Comment: The `InnerException` is still retrievable, though, which preserves the original stack trace (along with the entire context of the original exception details, if you want anything else). `.InnerException` just gives you that underlying `Exception` instance.

Comment: Exception messages are quite misleading, specially when automatically translated to other languages, as is with PT-BR. 
The most annoyingly confusing one is the FormatException one, which throws `A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto`, or "The inbound string of characters was _NOT_ in an incorrect format".

Comment: @EricWu for the future I would suggest creating an issue on .NET's github repository: that kind of error will only get fixed if reported.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the exception message via reflection like this...

```cs
Exception exception = new Exception("Some message.");
var type = typeof(Exception);
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var fieldInfo = type.GetField("_message", flags);
fieldInfo.SetValue(exception, message);
```

So you can create an extension method...

```cs
namespace ExceptionExample
{
    public static class ExceptionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetMessage(this Exception exception, string message)
        {
            if (exception == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exception));

            var type = typeof(Exception);
            var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var fieldInfo = type.GetField("_message", flags);
            fieldInfo.SetValue(exception, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it...

```cs
...
using static ExceptionExample.ExceptionExtensions;

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var reader = AnotherClass.GetReader();
        try
        {
            reader.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var connection = reader?.Connection;
            ex.SetMessage($"The exception message was replaced.\n\nOriginal message: {ex.Message}\n\nDatabase: {connection?.Database}");
            throw; // you will not lose the stack trace
        }
    }
}
```

You have to keep in mind that **if you use "throw ex;" the stack trace will be lost**.

To avoid this **you must use "throw;" without the exception**.

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to chime in here for Ian related to his answer. If you use the technique in the [blog post](http://tech.blinemedical.com/when-its-good-to-catch-exception-ex/) you won't lose the stack. Yes, you will lose the stack in the member of `StackTrace` of the final exception, but you won't lose the stack overall because of the inner exceptions. Look here:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Test1();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void Test1()
    {
        try
        {
            Test2();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ExceptionUtil.Rethrow(ex, "caught in test1");
        }
    }

    public static void Test2()
    {
        throw new Exception("test2");
    }

    public static class ExceptionUtil
    {
        public static Exception Rethrow(Exception ex, string message)
        {
            if (ex == null)
            {
                ex = new Exception("Error rethrowing exception because original exception is <null>.");
            }

            Exception rethrow;

            try
            {
                rethrow = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(ex.GetType(), message, ex);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                rethrow = new Exception(message, ex);
            }
            return rethrow;
        }

        public static Exception Rethrow(Exception ex, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            string formatted;

            try
            {
                formatted = String.Format(message, args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                formatted = message + "\r\n\r\nAn error occurred filling in exception message details:\r\n\r\n" + ex2;
            }
            return Rethrow(ex, formatted);
        }
    }

}
```

If you take the exception's full string you'll get:

```
System.Exception: caught in test1 ---> System.Exception: test2
at ScratchPad2.Program.Test2() in C:\Projects\Experiments\ScratchPad2\Program.cs:line 36
at ScratchPad2.Program.Test1() in C:\Projects\Experiments\ScratchPad2\Program.cs:line 26
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at ScratchPad2.Program.Test1() in C:\Projects\Experiments\ScratchPad2\Program.cs:line 30
at ScratchPad2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Experiments\ScratchPad2\Program.cs:line 14
```

So you got the whole stack anyways, plus extra information

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the previous exception in a new one with your new message and make use of the inner exception for the stack trace/etc.

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("This error message sucks");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("There error message is prettier", e);
}
```

Comment: Problem with that is that my new exception's stack trace doesn't match the old exception's stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace of the inner exception should be preserved so you can look for it there.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question but I don't think any of the existing answers are ideal (they hide exception details in innerExceptions or mask line numbers). The approach I use is to instantiate the exception using a static factory method instead of the constructor:

```
public class CustomException {
   public string SampleProperty { get; set; }

    public static CustomException FromAlert(Alert alert)
    {
        var ex = new CustomException(string.Format("{0}-{1}", alert.propertyA, alert.propertyB));
        ex.SampleProperty = "somethign else";
        return ex;
    }
}
```

So you can now throw:

`throw CustomException.FromAlert(theAlert);`

And modify the message to your hearts content.

Comment: Yepp. Strange that no one advised to use the factory method previously. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to write your own exception class that fits this particular situation. Then catch the exception, and throw your own Exception. You might want to see here: [Exception Constructors -> Exception(String) | MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx)  for more info.

If you feel a custom exception is not necessary, you should be able to pass a custom string to the Exception constructor when throwing an exception: Designing [Custom Exceptions | MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ca3hhw.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to throw my new exception where the old exception came from, rather than having it be traced to my `throw`?

Answer (score 1):

In my little old opinion, the best way to do it is inherit from Exception (or some other framework-supplied exception class as appropriate), then put your message string in a call to the base constructor which takes Message as a parameter, like so:

```
public class InvalidGraphicTypeException : Exception
{

   public InvalidGraphicTypeException(Graphic badType) : 
      base("Invalid Graphic Type: " + badType.GetType().Name)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: But then you're limited to whatever you can do in one-line/inline. If you need to do some additional work to figure out what the message should be you're out of luck.